# Disable Button When EditText Is Empty Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new, I don't have any experience. I saw some code to disable the login button. I tried to add it to the code. But I did not succeed. The application stops when the login button is pressed when the fields are empty.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Logging in...");

        if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email, pass;

                email = binding.emailBox.getText().toString();
                pass = binding.passwordBox.getText().toString();

                dialog.show();

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        binding.createNewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just checking for the empty fields, you should check for `email` pattern and for `password`, you should check if length > 6 otherwise `Firebase Auth` will throw an exception. Use below code for your `submitBtn` listener:

```
        binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = binding.emailBox.getText().toString();
                String pass = binding.passwordBox.getText().toString();

                if (email.isEmpty()) {
                    binding.emailBox.setError("Email is required");
                    binding.emailBox.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                    binding.emailBox.setError("Email is not valid");
                    binding.emailBox.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (pass.isEmpty()) {
                    binding.passwordBox.setError("Password is required");
                    binding.passwordBox.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (pass.length() < 6) {
                    binding.passwordBox.setError("Password is weak");
                    binding.passwordBox.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                
                dialog.show();

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```